# GA Statistics based on values UPDATED in google analitycs

Tags: android, google-analytics

i want to track some values in Google Analytics that are UPDATED not ADDED to the analytics data.

For example, if i want to track what is the average high score among all my users to be able to fine tune the scoring system.

I can add new value of high score every time the game exits, but it will be incremental, the old data from the same user won't be overwritten. So i won't get proper average values.

Is there a way to overwrite the old data in GA?

NOTE:
After filtering based on last update date - this could be used to figure out why your users uninstalled the app and many other things.

Comment: no you cant update GA data.

Comment: Any other workaround?

Comment: Heads up I posted this to the GA dev group on G+ to see if we can get some more help on the question:  https://plus.google.com/117200475532672775346/posts/NbxMravqkdN

Comment: Thanx, i hope this will move things in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround to long for a comment no idea if this will work or not:

First I don't know the Android GA side of things but I do have a lot of expense with GA development in general.

When tracking Ecommerce data the only way to remove a transaction is to add a new transaction value of negative the amount you want to remove.   This might work in your situation as well, but I wonder if the users will see the negative value when you display them there scores.

Example:

1. User score : 100    ( the original score)
2. delete score: -100  ( removing it)
3. user score: 40      ( re-add the new score)

This will technically mean that there are 3 lines for the user score but when added up by the system they should = the new score.

Again this is how its done in Ecommerce, if this works for you with this I would love to know for future reference I don't think you will be the only one trying to do this.

Comment: Nice idea, but you have to do this in a transaction. I'm not sure if there is a guarantee that an GA will submit the value or not. This still could work when the amount of failures to submit scores is reasonably low and you don't want the data to be 100% accurate.

Comment: It was the only thing I could think of :)

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind DalmTo's answer is fine, except I would use either event tracking or custom dimensions/metrics. Try the following:

User99 finished their first game with a high score of 125. Send an event with the following structure:

**Event Category**: User High Score
**Event Action**: User99
**Event Label**: (none) 
**Event Value**: 125

When the user plays again and attains a score of 139, send another event with the difference

**Event Category**: User High Score
**Event Action**: User99
**Event Label**: (none) 
**Event Value**: 14

With that data in GA, looking at the events report under the **User High Score** category will give you a breakdown per user (the **Event Action**), with the **Event Value** being the high score for that user.

If you need non-integer values for the high score, then use a custom metric instead.

Depending on your reporting needs, it might be just as easy to define a custom dimension for **User ID** and a custom metric for **High Score** and then send a pageview to */game-finished* when the game is finished, with those 2 values set accordingly.